# PHP save image created from imagecopy as blob

Tags: php, sql, image, png

I'm trying to merge two `PNG` images. I'm using the `imagecopy` function like this:

```
imagecopy($dest, $src, $dest_x / 2 - $src_x / 2, $dest_y / 2 - $src_y / 2, 0, 0, $src_x, $src_y);
```

Now, I want to save this merged photo as a `blob` in my DB, but the code doesn't work. My image is saved as a `14Bytes` object when a normal pic has about `100KB`.

```
 try
  {
      $stmt = $user->get_db()->prepare("INSERT INTO photos(id_user, src, date) VALUES(:id_user, :src, :date)");


      $stmt->bindparam(":id_user", $_SESSION['user_id']);
      $stmt->bindparam(":src", $dest);
      $stmt->bindparam(":date", date("Y-m-d H:i:s"));
      $stmt->execute();

  }
   catch(PDOException $e)
   {
        echo $e->getMessage();
   }
```

[image: Images in DB]

The first one is a successfully saved imaged (normal `png` image).
The second one is the merged imaged, wrongly uploaded.
The problem is when I upload the merged photo because it is not correctly uploaded.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suspect your issue is that passing the `$dest` parameter is not an actual image.

Try something like this after your `imagecopy`:

```
ob_start();
imagepng($dest);
$image_blob = ob_get_clean();
```

This should create the image into the variable.

Also, try adding 3rd parameter `PDO::PARAM_LOB` to `bind`, i.e.:

`$stmt->bindparam(":src", $image_blob, PDO::PARAM_LOB)`

You can read more about [PDO Large Objects](http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.lobs.php) you should use them in this case:

> Large typically means "around 4kb or more"
>
> Large objects can be either textual or binary in nature.

I hope this helps.